# Reset Href after changing it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I reset an href after changing it using jQuery (or javascript)?

I change the URL by appending a keyword. But each time the user changes the keyword or clicks submit, the keyword keeps getting appended to the last URL. I want new keywords to be added only to the original URL.

Note: I do not have access to the original URLs via javascript - they are created using WordPress (PHP/HTML/MySQL).

Working example:

```js
(function($) {
  $( "button" ).click(function() {

    // Get and display user's keyword
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("keyword").value;
    document.getElementById('display-keyword').innerHTML = "keyword: " + inputVal;


    // For each external URL
    $( ".launch a" ).each(function() {

      var testAppURL = $( this ).attr("href"); // external URL
      var launchURL = testAppURL + inputVal;  // new external URL
        
      $( this ).attr("href", launchURL); // Set href to new external URL
      $( this ).html(launchURL);

    });
    
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a keyword" id="keyword">
<button type="button">Set Keyword</button>

<p id='display-keyword'>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="launch">
  <a href="https://www.example.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Launch Me</a>
  <a href="https://www.websitenumb2.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Launch Me</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't use external code representations like fiddles, codepens etc. **unless the StackOverflow snippet functionality isn't sufficient to demonstrate your issue.** Questions seeking debugging help need to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem **in the question itself**.

Comment: Wow, first time I've seen someone complain about *providing* code in a question!  I heartily disagree with @connexo: there is nothing wrong here, as OP still posted the relevant code inline.

Comment: @machineghost You may want to read my comment again.

Comment: Does this problem concern changing the href on both links or continually appending to the href?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save the original URL in a data attribute and restore to that:

```js
(function($) {
  $( "button" ).click(function() {

    // Get and display user's keyword
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("keyword").value;
    document.getElementById('display-keyword').innerHTML = "keyword: " + inputVal;


    // For each external URL
    $( ".launch a" ).each(function() {

      var testAppURL = $( this ).attr("href"); // external URL
      var launchURL = $( this ).attr("data-href") + inputVal;  // new external URL
        
      $( this ).attr("href", launchURL); // Set href to new external URL
      $( this ).html(launchURL);

    });
    
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter a keyword" id="keyword">
<button type="button">Set Keyword</button>

<p id='display-keyword'>&nbsp;</p>

<div class="launch">
  <a href="https://www.example.com/" data-href="https://www.example.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Launch Me</a>
  <a href="https://www.websitenumb2.com/" data-href="https://www.websitenumb2.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Launch Me</a>
</div>
```